# ios Check phone number of american valid or not

Tags: ios

i want check the a string is or not match to american phone number?
(xxx)xxx-xxxx or
xxx-xxx-xxxx

please help me,thank you.

Comment: Possible Duplicate Question and Answer too.[Review](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18269743/ios-check-phone-number-of-american-valid-or-not)

Answer (score 2):

Use

https://github.com/rmaddy/RMPhoneFormat

And Check like

For Australia

```
RMPhoneFormat *formet = [RMPhoneFormat instance];
NSString *MyCode = [formet callingCodeForCountryCode:@"AU"];
NSString *defaultCallingCode = [formet defaultCallingCode];
```

For India

```
RMPhoneFormat *formet = [RMPhoneFormat instance];
NSString *MyCode = [formet callingCodeForCountryCode:@"IN"];
NSString *defaultCallingCode = [formet defaultCallingCode];
```

...

Here MyCode is  return **code of Country** , such like..

> **For** Australia it return - 67
>   **For** India it return - 91

Comment: but i don't found the file with name PhoneFormats.dat.

Comment: what ?? i can not understand ?

Comment: when i build the PhoneFormats project. error:error: /Users/konnech05/Downloads/RMPhoneFormat-master/RMPhoneFormat-master/RMPhoneFormat/PhoneFormats.dat: No such file or directory

Answer (score 2):

I think the best solution would be using [RMPhoneFormat](https://github.com/rmaddy/RMPhoneFormat).

As the description says :

```
RMPhoneFormat *fmt = [[RMPhoneFormat alloc] init];
// Call any number of times
NSString *numberString = // the phone number to validate
BOOL valid = [fmt isPhoneNumberValid:fmt];
```

Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

This should be easily done with regular expressions. Go through this document http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html and try to make regular expression to check if string matches American phone number pattern.
There are lots of really good tutorials about objective-c regular expressions on the Internet.